# What is the least privilege necessary in Azure AD for a user that is the organization owner in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to determine the least privilege necessary in Azure AD for a user account that serves simply as the organization owner in Azure DevOps.  I want to provide the appropriate amount of privileges to allow that user account to fulfill the role of organization owner in Azure DevOps, but no more than is necessary.

Comment: You were correct.  An Azure DevOps owner does not need specific permissions in Azure AD.

Comment: If the below answer is helpful to you,you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the question makes sense, fairly certain organization owner can do anything inside the organization

Comment: Organization owner in Azure DevOps is not the same as the tenant owner in Azure AD.  I'm trying to find a listing of the permissions needed by the Organization Owner in Azure DevOps.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: He doesnt need any privileges in Azure AD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-organization-ownership?view=azure-devops#prerequisites